# Get User Access Token - Facebook Marketing API

Tags: c#, facebook, api, restsharp

I'm using RestSharp to make a call to the Facebook API and it's returning the App Access Token.

However I need to return the User Access Token instead as I need this to create offline conversion sets using the Marketing API.

I've given the app all the appropriate permissions and I can verify this using the Access Token Tool.

Can someone help? Thanks

```
public void getToken(string uriauth, string clientid, string client_secret, string redirect_uri)
    {

        RestSharp.Deserializers.JsonDeserializer deserial = new RestSharp.Deserializers.JsonDeserializer();

        var client = new RestClient(uriauth);// + "?client_id=" + clientid + "&client_secret=" + client_secret + "&grant_type=client_credentials");
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);

        //request.Resource = "{request_string}";

        request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
        request.AddHeader("content-type", "text/javascript; charset=utf-8");
        request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=" + clientid + "&client_secret=" + client_secret, ParameterType.RequestBody);

        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

        if (response.Content.ToString().Contains("access") == false)
        {
            try
            {
                throw new System.Exception("Token API doesn't work");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Dts.Events.FireError(0, "ERROR", ex.Message, null, 0);
                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
                return;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Token returnData = deserial.Deserialize<Token>(response);

            if (returnData.access_token != null)
            {
                access_token = returnData.access_token;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: you can only get a user token with user interaction. there is no way to get a user token with code only.

Comment: I've managed to generate the user token using the front-end and have tested this successfully in the Graph Explorer. Am I supposed to hard-code the token into my code if I want to create offline conversion data sets?

Comment: No, you shouldn't hard code it. You should retrieve it as necessary from your database or other when needed.

Comment: Thanks Patrick, So every time the token expires, I'd need to generate a new one and update my application to refer to the new token? Surely that's a very strange way of doing it. I thought it would be easy enough to generate it in my code?

Comment: no, user tokens are bound to a user, so they have to be generated with user interaction. would be weird if you could just generate one without authorization of the user. extended user tokens are valid for 60 days, after that you have to refresh it - with user interaction. the point is: no app should be able to use a user token if the user did not use the app for more than 60 days.

Comment: Thanks luschn. I'm creating the user token by going to Facebook Business Manager > System Users > Generate New Token. However, I can also generate a token in my App by going to Marketing API > Tools. I'm guessing generating it for the System User is the correct way of doing it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Decided to generate the user token in facebook and pass it into my C# script via an SSIS variable